# LuaRocks fPIC error

Tags: lua, compiler-errors, luarocks

I'm trying to install numlua with luarocks:

```
luarocks make numlua-0.3-1.rockspec
```

but am getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: numlua.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
numlua.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
cp: cannot stat `numlua.so': No such file or directory
```

I'm guessing I need to add the -fPIC argument as a flag but not being great with compilers and a first-timer with luaRocks I'm not sure how or where to add this, or, if there is something else I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [this mailing list discussion](http://lists.luaforge.net/pipermail/luarocks-developers/2008-December/000942.html), it looks like LuaRocks is configured for a 32-bit system while actually running on a 64-bit system. It's likely that you installed it via a package manager, as this shouldn't happen when installed from source.

Find your `luarocks/config.lua` file. On my Ubuntu 11.10 system, it was located at `/usr/share/lua/5.1/luarocks/config.lua`. Find the line that says `LUAROCKS_UNAME_M` and change the `i686` to `x86_64`.

Now that luarocks knows it's on a 64-bit machine, numlua should compile fine.

Comment: Ideally, users of distributions that ship LuaRocks misconfigured like that should post bug reports to their distros of choice. It would help us all!